# How to filter the items starting with "OO" from the list

Tags: c#, .net, filter

I need to loop the `List<string>` and then extract the specified items which start with "OO" to a new list of strings.

Here is my code:

```
List<string> mylist = new List<string>() 
Mylist.add("5876575");
Mylist.add("OO12571");
Mylist.add("12287324");
Mylist.add("87665751");
Mylist.add("97213233");
Mylist.add("87612222");
Mylist.add("OO76566");


List<string> matches = new List<string>() 
matches = myList.Where(x => x[0] == 'OO').ToList();
```

My above code is not working. Please help me.
The output should be a matches list which should only contain the item starts with "OO":

> Matches = OO12571, OO76566

Comment: `x[0] == 'OO'` Really?  The first character cannot equal 2 characters.  It also looks like the strings have the letter `O` while the code is trying to match zeroes.

Comment: Erm `myList.Where(x => x.StartsWith("OO"))` maybe?

Comment: `“”` for quotes? Did you copy this code from Microsoft Word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, your attached code has plenty of compilation errors.

Assume that you have fixed it, there are quite some alternatives to filter the string in the array/list with starts with "OO".

1. `string.StartsWith()` as suggested by @Charlieface

```cs
matches = mylist.Where(x => x.StartsWith("OO"))
    .ToList();
```

2. Take the first 2 characters with `string.Substring(0, 2)`.

```cs
matches = mylist.Where(x => x.Substring(0, 2) == "OO")
    .ToList();
```

3. Working with Regex.

```cs
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

Regex regex = new Regex("^OO");
matches = mylist.Where(x => regex.IsMatch(x))
    .ToList();
```